# How to make Listbox to not remember its last view

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox, stackpanel, remember-me, virtualizingstackpanel

I have a `Listbox` that bind to an `ObservableCollection`. In my app, I need to clear this collection in `OnNavigatedFrom` and read it in `OnNavigatedTo` to reduced memory.

However, I see that when using `StackPanel` as `ItemsPanelTemplate`, `Listbox` can remember its last view (its seletected item), while `VirtualizingStackPanel` does not.

So how can I disable this behavior when using `StackPanel` ?

Comment: set the selectedindex to -1?

Answer (score 0):

It is a common problem, you need to set the Listbox's SelectedIndex to -1